# Is there any particular reason why all Turkey-related questions were bumped today?

Tags: discussion

I am curious whether there is a particular reason behind this. This apparently  also happened in the Politics SE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is quite simple: A spammer thought it a good idea to promote his Turkish related product under all these questions.

Comment: Same spammer did the same on politics.SE :-/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Unwelcome as (s)he was with this stupid move, the speed to deletion is actually a good sign for a very healthy community ;)

Comment: Indeed. Also makes me wonder why this person kept up the spam, as some posts were removed in as little as 15 seconds ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯